# How to get value inside JSON using PowerShell

Tags: json, windows, powershell

My Task was to find print the ID from below JSON file using PowerShell

```
{
    "comment": "abcd",
    "server":{
        "guid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = (Get-Content "Yourpath of JSON" -Raw ) | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.server.guid
```